# Angular IE11 not working. Getting SCRIPT1002 Syntax Error

Tags: angular, internet-explorer

Trying to get Angular to work in IE 11.
I tried everything I found on the web already.

I'm getting the following errors:

> SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
>
> File: polyfills.js, Line: 2358, Column: 1

Line 2358

```
class Disposable {

    /**
     * Frees internal resources.
     */

    dispose() {}

}
```

> SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
>
> File: scripts.js, Line: 424, Column: 35

line 424

```
let SoapService = SoapService_1 = class SoapService {
    constructor(servicePort, servicePath, targetNamespace) {
        this.debug = false;
        this.asynchronous = true;
        this.localName = false;
        this.servicePort = '';
        this.servicePath = '';
        this.serviceUrl = '';
        this.targetNamespace = '';
        this.envelopeBuilder_ = null;
        this.xmlResponseHandler_ = null;
        this.jsoResponseHandler_ = null;
        this.servicePort = servicePort;
        this.servicePath = servicePath;
        this.serviceUrl = servicePort + servicePath;
        if (undefined !== targetNamespace)
            this.targetNamespace = targetNamespace;
    }
```

> SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
>
> File: vendor.js, Line: 88, Column: 1

Line 88

```
class AnimationBuilder {
}
```

> SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
>
> File: main.js, Line: 91422, Column: 35

Line 91422 Same as above

```
    let SoapService = SoapService_1 = class SoapService {
        constructor(servicePort, servicePath, targetNamespace) {
....
```

I do have a soap connection which wont work on localhost anyway. So thats probably not the problem

Added this line in main.ts

`/// <reference path= "../node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts" />`

Added this script in index.html

```
<script src="/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,

  "compilerOptions": 
  {
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames":true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom",
      "es5",
      "es6"
    ]
  },

  "files": [
    "src/app/app.module.ts"
  ],

  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

I also have a tsconfig.app.json and tsconfig.spec.json

**polyfills.js**

```
/**
 * This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
 * You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
 *
 * This file is divided into 2 sections:
 *   1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are sorted by browsers.
 *   2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be loaded before your main
 *      file.
 *
 * The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions of browsers that
 * automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 (including Opera),
 * Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
 *
 * Learn more in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';


/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
// Used for reflect-metadata in JIT. If you use AOT (and only Angular decorators), you can remove.



/**
 * Required to support Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`.
 * Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox and Opera. http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-animation
 **/
import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.



/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.



/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */
import 'three';
import 'three-orbitcontrols-ts';
import 'postprocessing';
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "regalplaner",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^7.0.0",
    "@tweenjs/tween.js": "^17.2.0",
    "@types/three": "^0.92.20",
    "autopulous-angular2-soap": "^0.4.7",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "dat.gui": "^0.7.5",
    "es6-tween": "^5.3.0",
    "n": "^2.1.12",
    "ng-drag-drop": "^5.0.0",
    "ng2-drag-drop": "^3.0.2",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^6.7.0",
    "normalize.css": "^5.0.0",
    "postprocessing": "^5.3.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
    "stats-js": "^1.0.0",
    "three": "^0.94.0",
    "three-addons": "^1.2.0",
    "three-gltf-loader": "^1.102.0",
    "three-orbitcontrols-ts": "^0.1.2",
    "tween.js": "^16.6.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.10.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.1",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: What code is on each of the lines throwing an error?

Comment: @scunliffe updated

Comment: Update to the latest cli
Create a new cli project
go in polyfills.ts and un- comment lines: 22 - 35.
Run ng serve and check if that works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**For others running across similar issues:**

Angular 8 has made the default target `es2015` instead of `es5`

You'll want to create a `tsconfig.es5.json` so that you only run on es5 in development mode, but more information on that can be found here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14455

You'll also want to uncomment the polyfills in `polyfills.ts` depending on what you are using.

**For others and for the asker:**

Then, you'll want to add a flag to zone.js

Add `import './zone-flags.ts';`
before `import 'zone.js/dist/zone';`
then create the `zone-flags.ts` file in the same directory as the `polyfills.ts`.

In the `zone-flags.ts` file add the following line:

`(window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;`

Hopefully after that everything is working! If you followed the link above,

Execute: `ng serve --configuration es5` to run your project in IE in development mode.

**Update**

It looks like angular actually has documentation on this:
[angular.io/guide/deployment#fallback](http://angular.io/guide/deployment#fallback)

Look for "Local development in older browsers" and then "Configuring serve for ES5"

The issue is caused by Angular 8's differential loading process.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using or transpiring down your JavaScript but it isn't going far enough and you are getting syntax issues because you are trying to use features that IE11 doesn't support.

e.g.

- JS Classes - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes
- JS Constructors - (part of classes, see above)

Answer (score 0):

To complete what [@Lionheart Scholar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10028822/lionheart-scholar) said, there is one final step: registering the zone-flags.ts file in the tsconfig.app.json "files" section, like so:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts",
    "src/zone-flags.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -3):

In tsconfig.json
replace  "target": "es5",
       //"target": "es2015",

Comment: if u did that and forgot. Your build will be using es5.